# Can I post a question requesting opinions on certain books in Physics Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

I think that opinion-based questions are not accepted in Physics Stack Exchange but I just wanted to ask:
Can I post a question requesting opinions on certain books in Physics Stack Exchange?

Comment: You can always ask [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), though it's only well populated during roughly the US working day i.e. from about 17:00 UTC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*No.* In fact one of the current close reasons is precisely that answers would be *primarily opinion-based.*